# Controlling states of navbar-toggle button in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

As it stands when I activate my navbar dropdown toggle button in mobile view, its color goes from dark black (hover color) to grey, as the menu drops down. However, when you click outside of the button, it reverts to its default, non-hover color (lighter shade of black), despite the menu still being dropped down.

So, my first question is, how do I maintain that active color regardless of what you do as long as the menu is dropped down?

My second problem is, when you click the button for the second time, causing the menu to hide, it maintains its active color (grey); I want it to inherit its default, non-hover color of the lighter shade of black.

How do I do this? [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PFm7YsKlpu)

HTML:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class = "dropdown"> 
                            <a href = "" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span></span></a>
                            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "#"></a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#"></a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->

                    </ul><!-- END: "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" -->
                </div><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
              </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a way to do that with just CSS, I don't know how.  To do what you want, first you need a couple CSS changes, then some Javascript (I'm using jQuery here for convenience).

First, delete the `.navbar-toggle:focus` definition, since `:focus` can't do what you want.

Second, put your desired background color in a class that you will toggle on and off (I'll call it `.menuActive`).

```
.menuActive { background-color: #666; }
```

Third comes the toggling code. If I understand you correctly, you want bg color to turn grey when the user clicks and the menu appears, and then revert to the default color when the user clicks again and the menu disappears.  Assuming you're using jQuery, insert the following into your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('menuActive');
});
```

If you need more control than `.toggleClass()` gives you, you can also keep track of the state yourself and use the `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods.

Comment: Okay, cool this works, but for some reason, when I take out the definition you told me to take out, default CSS is interfering with my custom stuff, resulting in some really glitchy stuff. You know what I'm talking about?

Comment: @ReachMM Could you explain more what you mean? Which default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I want to share a better solution.

Bootstrap navbar use their [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to toggle the menu. So it's better to watch for collapse events and then toggle class on the `.navbar-toggle`. Here is an example:

```
$('.navbar .navbar-collapse')
  .on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('menu closed');
    $('.navbar .navbar-toggle').removeClass('active');
  })
  .on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    console.log('menu open');
    $('.navbar .navbar-toggle').addClass('active');
  });
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap 5, you can use `collapsed` class.

```
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) {
           //some style
    }
```